# GTM - Bad Event Tracking Code - Pageview Hit must precede event

Tags: google-tag-manager, analytics-events

I'm having trouble finding a GTM error. The error states that Google Tag Manager isn't receiving the URL/page-name in Google's Behavior->Landing Pages report before it receives an event.

I'm not sure how to find the offending page and of course, Google can't tell me the offending page, so trying to use Google's Tag Assistant would mean testing every single page on the website.

The error appears to be happening on all of the major browsers, so it doesn't seem to be browser specific.

I tried to lookup one session by matching the session duration with user sessions.  The session begins at 11:58 pm and ends at 12:04 am.  However, when I use Google's Tag Assistant, it doesn't show any errors.

[image]

If this were the problem page, it would appear that GTM looses the page name when the session wraps over the midnight hour, but this seems improbable.

[image]

How can I properly identify the offending page without using Google Tag Assistant on every single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have an error on your pages.
If that is the case you can select to ignore the diagnostic message in the interface (or possibly select it as resolved via the diagnostic message- you'll have to check that, brain is a bit hazy on it).

Based on your timezone settings in GA, sessions that are current at midnight will end and generate a new session.

Therefore if a user is browsing a page, and it hits midnight, the pageview for the page has already fired for the session prior to midnight.
So the first hit in the new session, is likely to be an event, based on the page scroll event tracking that is in place.

> **End of day expiry** Bob opens your website at 11:50 PM on the 14th of August and leaves your website at 12:10 AM on the 15th of August.
>
> The first session ends at 11:59:59 PM on the 14th of August, and the
>   second session begins at 12:00 AM on the 15th of August.
>
> End of day is determined by your view timezone settings.
>   **Ref:** https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en